# jenkins CI/CD pipeline to build and publish multiple microservice .net application on the server

Tags: .net, jenkins, build, microservices, cicd

I am working on the project of .net application ,which has multiple microservices. Now we want to build all the microservices and publish them into the server.

Please guide me through the proper approach that should be followed to acheive this.
Do i need to create seperate job for each microservice and build it seperately,or do we have any other approach to do this.?
Please help.

Comment: This is out of scope for SO, see my post here for some guidance though - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/06/04/7-best-practices-modern-cicd/